# Creating dummy columns from cells with multiple values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a DF as shown below:

```
DF =
id  Result      
1   Li_In-AR-B, Or_Ba-AR-B
1   Li_In-AR-L, Or_Ba-AR-B
3   N
4   Lo_In-AR-U
5   Li_In-AR-U
6   Or_Ba-AR-B
6   Or_Ba-AR-L
7   N
```

Now I want to create new columns for every unique value in `Result` before the first "-". Every other value in the new column should be set to `N`. The delimiter "," is used to separate both instances in case of multiple values (2 or more).

```
DF =
id  Result        Li_In         Lo_In       Or_Ba
1   Li_In-AR-B    Li_In-AR-B    N           Or_Ba-AR-B
1   Li_In-AR-L    Li_In-AR-L    N           Or_Ba-AR-B
3   N             N             N           N
4   Lo_In-AR-U    N             Lo_In-AR-U  N
5   Li_In-AR-U    Li_In-AR-U    N           N
6   Or_Ba-AR-B    N             N           Or_Ba-AR-B
6   Or_Ba-AR-L    N             N           Or_Ba-AR-L
7   N             N             N           N
```

I thought I could do this easily using `.get_dummies` but this only returns a binary value for each cell.

```
DF_dummy = DF.Result.str.get_dummies(sep='-')
DF = pd.concat([DF,DF_dummy ],axis=1)
```

Also this solution for an earlier post is not applicable for the new case.

```
m = DF['Result'].str.split('-', n=1).str[0].str.get_dummies().drop('N', axis=1) == 1
df1 = pd.concat([DF['Result']] * len(m.columns), axis=1, keys=m.columns)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There was typo, now solution working nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dictionary comprehension` with `DataFrame` constructor for split by `,\s+` for split by coma with one or more whitespaces.

```
import re
f = lambda x: {y.split('-', 1)[0] : y for y in re.split(',\s+', x) if y != 'N' } 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(DF['Result'].apply(f).values.tolist(), index=DF.index).fillna('N')
print (df1)
        Li_In       Lo_In       Or_Ba
0  Li_In-AR-B           N  Or_Ba-AR-B
1  Li_In-AR-L           N  Or_Ba-AR-B
2           N           N           N
3           N  Lo_In-AR-U           N
4  Li_In-AR-U           N           N
5           N           N  Or_Ba-AR-B
6           N           N  Or_Ba-AR-L
7           N           N           N
```

Last add to original `DataFrame`:

```
df = DF. join(df1) 
print (df)
   id                  Result       Li_In       Lo_In       Or_Ba
0   1  Li_In-AR-B, Or_Ba-AR-B  Li_In-AR-B           N  Or_Ba-AR-B
1   1  Li_In-AR-L, Or_Ba-AR-B  Li_In-AR-L           N  Or_Ba-AR-B
2   3                       N           N           N           N
3   4              Lo_In-AR-U           N  Lo_In-AR-U           N
4   5              Li_In-AR-U  Li_In-AR-U           N           N
5   6              Or_Ba-AR-B           N           N  Or_Ba-AR-B
6   6              Or_Ba-AR-L           N           N  Or_Ba-AR-L
7   7                       N           N           N           N
```

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again but what would I need to change if "Li_In-AR1-B, Li_In-AR2-B" was my column value and I would like to only keep the first ("Li_In-AR1-B"?). Right now it takes the last element if the words before the "-AR" part are the same.

Comment: I think need `f = lambda x: {y.split('-', 1)[0] : y for y in reversed(re.split(',\s+', x)) if y != 'N' } `

Comment: Only reverse `list` created by `re.split`